# Unable to connect to Remote Server using Selenium Chrome RemoteWebDriver

Tags: c#, selenium, sockets, remotewebdriver

```
public static IWebDriver UserMultiUserSignIn (IWebDriver driver, string port, string hostName, string password, string Username)
{
    string name = Dns.GetHostName();
    ChromeOptions Options = new ChromeOptions();
    Options.AddAdditionalCapability(Username, "USERNAME");
    Options.AddAdditionalCapability(password, "ACCESS_KEY");
    driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://"+hostName+":"+port+ "/wd/hub"), Options.ToCapabilities());            

    return driver;
}


public static void RemoteServerLogin ()
{            
    string EMAUserName = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("EMAUserName");
    string Password = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("EMAPassword");
    string Port = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("Port");
    string HostName = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("Hostname");

    UserMultiUserSignIn(driver, Port, HostName, Password, EMAUserName);
}
```

Exception :

> OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: 'Unexpected error.
>   System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server --->
>   System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made
>   because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:9515    at
>   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot,
>   SocketAddress socketAddress)    at
>   System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure,
>   Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address,
>   ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception&
>   exception)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context) 
>   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()    at
>   OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.MakeHttpRequest(HttpRequestInfo
>   requestInfo)    at
>   OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.Execute(Command
>   commandToExecute)    at
>   OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String
>   driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)'

Comment: The IP addrress 127.0.0.1 is the loopback IP address and every machine that has a Ethernet interface is required to have a loopback address.  If you are connecting to a remote machine than you have to use the remote machine IP address or computer name.  The error indicates a connection couldn't be made which is normally due to one of the following 1) The server is not listening 2) There is no IP route to the server (even if local) 3) The port is blocked 4) The credentials do not allow the connection, 4) Wrong IP or port is being used.

Comment: The Remote Server is active and listening. I am able to ping the server. The credentials are working fine manually and Port is not being used. I didnt find the solution to the issue even after trying with all the ways

Comment: You are not connecting to the remote server because the error is indicating the loopback address 127.0.0.1.  You have to replace the loopback address with the Remove Server IP or Computer Name.

Comment: This is not working. I tried replacing the loopback address with IP or Computer Name.

Comment: Use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and see what is really happening.  One the remote machine from cmd.exe >Netstat -a will tell if the application is listening.  If ping works, the server is listening, and the sniffer is showing a connection being established iit should work.  If you really changed the IP address you should not being getting a message the 127.0.0.1 actively refused the connection.